# WPF: Get Tag Property from ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf

I'm assigning a text to `Tag` property of the `Button` but how can I use it from `ResourceDictionary`.

My Button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ControlBarButton}" Tag="-"/>
```

I want to use Tag property from content of the button
My Resource Dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key="ControlBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

                <Button Width="35"
                        Content="I WANT TO USE `Tag` HERE">
                </Button>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why would you put a Button inside a Button? Why can't you just simply set the Content property locally instead of the Tag property? I guess you misunderstood something? What are you really trying to do? A simplified example is always good. but it shouldn't miss the key. Otherwise you dilute the problem.

Comment: You would have to use `TemplateBinding`. But if you want help to write good code or to find the best answer in general you should explain the bigger picture. What you have showed really doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @BionicCode I'm not only putting a Button inside of a Button. I will add some other propertys to button but. I need to get an access to Tag property.

Comment: It doesn't matter what else you are adding. The Button is already a button. You don't have to add another button into it to make it a button. You usually put a ContentPresenter into the ControlTemplate where you want the Content value to be placed and add whatever else you need. It's already a button. By overriding the template you only change how the control will look like or visually behave. It doesn't change the control's behavior. The element is still of type Button. Just don't do it. It's ridiculous.

Comment: If you show what you are exactly doing or trying then I or somebody else can help you to achieve it. You are very likely making your life too hard at this point. I hope you understand the problem. You just asked for help of a very very specific problem of which you believe is the right way to go. It obviously isn't. To get the best help you have to explain and show what your true goals are. Otherwise the only input you get is that you are doing nonsense. Or you get a solution that will introduce more problems - like nesting a Button inside a Button would attract wrong solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TemplateBinding` in the template:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ControlBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

                <Button Width="35"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}">
                </Button>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```